# is there a generic try catch for firebase on flutter that covers both iOS and android and show a progress bar

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

**1.** I want to be able to catch all errors thrown from *firebase*.
**2.** Secondly to show a progress indicator while the process is running and then if there is an error it, the catch would be able to handle any errors thrown by firebase, specific catch clause would be great also.

I have tried using catchError((e) "with a dialog that should pop-up",but it seems not to catch errors from firebase and nothing pops up, for the progress indactor is there any way to implement it in a way that it actually waits for the event to complete not some random number given to it.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can solve this issue or point a flutter newbie like me to an actual implementation. Thanks in advance

```
    FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: _email, password: _password)
                  .then((signedInUser) {
                Usermanagement().storeNewUser(signedInUser, context);
                saveUserD.addUser(regPage);
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/Somepage");
              }).catchError((e) {
                _invalidEmail(context); 
                //catchPassError();
                //print(e);
              });
```

I expect that progress indicator would show, when the user clicks the button and if for a reason it doesn't work due to some unseen error, the catch would pick-up any errors

Comment: Anyone who how to do this ??

Comment: the temporary fixed on github solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary fix on Github fixed the issue:

```
enum authProblems { UserNotFound, PasswordNotValid, NetworkError }
authProblems errorType;

if (Platform.isAndroid) {switch (e.message) {
case 'There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.':
  errorType = authProblems.UserNotFound;
  break;
case 'The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.':
  errorType = authProblems.PasswordNotValid;
  break;
case 'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.':
  errorType = authProblems.NetworkError;
  break;
// ...
default:
  print('Case ${e.message} is not jet implemented');}} 


else if (Platform.isIOS) {switch (e.code) {
case 'Error 17011':
  errorType = authProblems.UserNotFound;
  break;
case 'Error 17009':
  errorType = authProblems.PasswordNotValid;
  break;
case 'Error 17020':
  errorType = authProblems.NetworkError;
  break;
// ...
default:
  print('Case ${e.message} is not jet implemented'); }}
alertdialog();
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20223[1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20223)

I also put an alert dialog that pops up if the error is not defined